# WSL2 not recognizing my BIOS' enabled virtualization option

Tags: bios, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Thus it will not start my Ubuntu distro, assuming this is why. I have been working with this distro for the past week, I have not used it for about a day. This is the error I was originally given when trying to start it:

```
PS C:\Users\zenro> wsl
The operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/HCS_E_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

I have done some research into the topic and tried a few solutions including all of the typical on/off switches of WSL and the BIOS virtualization option. I have tried `wsl --install` as well.

```
PS C:\Users\zenro> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
  Ubuntu    Stopped         2
PS C:\Users\zenro> wsl --status
Default Distribution: Ubuntu
Default Version: 2
WSL2 is not supported with your current machine configuration.
Please enable the "Virtual Machine Platform" optional component and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
```

I have not installed anything in the time between it working and it not.

Any suggestions to fix this? I would rather not reinstall Windows, but if that's necessary I will.

Comment: Have you enabled the Windows feature of Virtual Machine Platform?